# Array[0] does not change while Bubblesort

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

> Hello there! Im sorry the code can not be shorter, every line could
>   matter for the output. This is a bubblesort code. QUELL is the FILE im
>   reading. The file has 3390 lines of numbers. /// Herer is the problem:
>   when I optput the sorted array, the first line always stays the same,
>   like it was never changed. How can I fix this?

```
    int sorta[3390];
    for(int i=0; i < 3390; ++i){
        fgets(string, MAXZEILE, QUELL);
        sscanf(string, "%d", &a);
        sorta[i]=a;
    }
    for(int y=0; y < 3390; ++y){
    for(int x=3388; x>y; --x){
        if (sorta[x] >= sorta[x+1]){
        int tmp = sorta[x];
        sorta[x] = sorta[x+1];
        sorta[x+1] = tmp;
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner loop iterates as long as `x>y`. This will miss the last iteration where you want x to equal y. To make a long story short - replace `>` with `>=` and you should be OK:

```
for(int y=0; y < 3390; ++y) {
    for(int x=3388; x >= y; --x) {
    // Here -----------^
```